# find rpm name from a executable

Tags: java, linux, rpm

I am using redhat 6.5. By default JRE is installed with this OS. I want to find the rpm name of the jre installed in my machine. 
ie) input should be executable and the output will be the rpm name

## which java

/usr/bin/java

expected output:

## command to find the rpm name.

jre-1.7.0_80-fcs.x86_64

here java --version shows version 1.5. But i want to use oracle jre instead of the default one. After installing oracle jre still the default version of jres is used but i want to remove the default version of jre from OS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's an administration, not a programming question. And all search engines should instantly yield useful results for "find package containing file redhat".

Answer (score 0):

The solution to you problem is , after installing the oracle version of java you have to use alternatives command to point to you default java, like follows:

```
   # alternatives --config java
```

and select the default version there.
Now check the version of java with `java --version`

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i want to know the command to find the name of rpm from the executable.